# Converting bibliography between latex document types

Tags: latex, bibtex

I have a paper on Overleaf, that I wrote with

```
\documentclass{siamart0516}
```

and I want to switch to

```
\documentclass{svjour3}
```

The transition works except for the bibliography (the paper compiles completely if I don't include it, or if I include a manual bibliography using `\begin{thebibliography}{}` and `\bibitem`). In the original file I used

```
\bibliographystyle{siamplain.bst}  
%\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{bibliography.bib}
```

For reference, unsrt works just fine (since I think siamplain.bst is nonstandard).

In the new file I want to use one of

```
\bibliographystyle{spbasic}
%\bibliographystyle{spmpsci}
```

My output varies by exactly what I try, but I have not been able to get this document class to work with either of these options (or my original options). The errors are not consistent, sometimes it's just a long output log with no defined error. One error I do get frequently is

```
White space in argument : \citation.
```

I am happy to use any workarounds, including different bst files that give a similar output, not really particular on fixing this specific error.

Comment: please make a [mre]